in flutter cannot get incoming call when the app is in background or terminated using fluttercallkitincoming package
I could not able to get incoming call when my app is in background in iOS but in android it is working fine using flutercallkitincoming package I could able to get the notifications but could not display the incoming call ui using fluttercallkit incoming package
I have tried of fluttercallkitincoming
